# Properly defining a subset of $\mathbb{Z}^k$

Tags: graph-theory, notation, definition, integer-lattices

I need to provide a good definition of the subset of $\{\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\} \times \{0,1,\ldots,n-1\} \times \cdots \times \{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}\} \subset \mathbb{Z}^k$ given by all the vertices of the aforementioned set that can be reached in a single move (or less) by a $k$-dimensional chess rook, $R$, that starts from the vertex $\{(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k)\}$ (i.e., $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k \in \{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$), where the generalized rook move rule is shown below. [[image: Rook move rule for <span class=]$n=4, k=3, x_1=1, x_2=0, x_3=0$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5WWQ.png)

Now, I think that my definition $$\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k\} \cup \{(x_1+c_1,x_2+c_2,\dots,x_k+c_k) : \exists \tilde{j} \in \{1,2,\dots,k\} : \\
((c_{j \neq \tilde{j}}=0 \wedge |c_{j=\tilde{j}}|=c  \wedge (|\{\tilde{j}\}|<|\{j\}|) \wedge (x_j+c_j) \in \{0,1,\dots,n-1\}) \quad \forall c \in \{1,2,\ldots,n-1\}), j=1,2,\ldots,k \}$$ is pretty ugly... is there a better way to indicate the described subset, working for any $n \in \mathbb{N}-\{0\}$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}-\{0,1\}$?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You should clarify the rook move rule.

Comment: As a clarifying example let $n=4$ and $k=3$. If we start with our rook in $(0,1,0)$, then we need to define the set $\{(1,0,0),(0,0,0),(2,0,0),(3,0,0),(0,1,0),(1,1,0),(2,1,0),(1,2,0),(3,2,0),(1,3,0),(0,0,1),(1,0,1),(2,0,1),(1,1,1),(1,0,2),(3,0,2),(1,2,2),(1,0,3),(1,3,3)\}$ as shown in the Figure above, while if the starting vertex is $(1,2,1)$ the set should be $\{(1,2,1),(1,1,0),(0,2,0),(1,2,0),(2,2,0),(1,3,0),(1,0,1),(3,0,1),(0,1,1),(1,1,1),(2,1,1),(0,2,1),(2,2,1),(3,2,1),(0,3,1),(1,3,1),(2,3,1),(1,1,2),(0,2,2),(1,2,2),(2,2,2),(1,3,2),(1,0,3),(1,2,3),(3,2,3)\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your set can be described as
$$
\bigcup_{1 \leqslant j \leqslant k} \bigl\{ (x_1, \ldots, x_{j-1}, c, x_{j+1}, \ldots, x_k) \mid c \in \{0, \ldots, n-1\} \bigr\}
$$
EDIT. New attempt, following the OP comments.
$$
\bigcup_{I \subsetneq \{1, \ldots, k\}} \bigcup_{c \in \{0, \ldots, n-1\}}
\Biggl\{ (z_1, \ldots, z_k) \mid z_i = 
\begin{cases}
c   &\text{if $i \in I$}\\
x_i &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
 \Biggr\}
$$

Comment: Thank you, but I think that this (nice) definition describes a standard $k$-dimensional rook that cannot change $2$ or more of its starting $k$ Cartesian coordinates at a time, whereas we may include in the definition also vertices of the form $(x_1+c, x_2+c, \ldots, x_{k-1}+c, x_k)$, or $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{k-1}+c, x_k+c)$, or $(x_1, x_2+c, \dots, x_{k-1}, x_k+c)$ and so forth, for any $c$ as above. While we should exclude the vertices belonging to the set $\{(x_1+c,x_2+c,\dots,x_{k-1}+c,x_k+c\}, c \in \{0,1,\ldots,n-1\})$ since our rook cannot change all its starting coordinates at a time.

Comment: In the last sentece of my previous comment, I should have pointed out to disregard the vertices belonging to $\{ \{(x_1+c,x_2+c,\ldots, x_{k-1}+c, x_k+c) \mid c \in \{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}\} -
 \{(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k)\}\}$, my bad.

Comment: I am a bit lost. Would $(x_1+c_1, x_2+c_2,x_3)$ be allowed only if $c_1=c_2$?

Comment: $|c_1|=|c_2| \wedge (x_1+c_1),(x_2+c_2) \in \{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$ or $c_1=0 \wedge c_2 \neq 0$ or  $c_2=0 \wedge c_1 \neq 0$. I know, it's a bit tricky...

Comment: P.S. If the edited formula works for the given case, that's a good answer for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Nobody will want to read a paragraph of set-builder notation. Words can be just as rigorous as symbols, and writing something that's easy to understand makes it more likely that there is no subtle mistake hidden in there.

I would write, for example:

> A $k$-dimensional rook can move from a square $(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_k)$ to a square $(y_1, y_2,\dots,y_k)$ in a single move if there is some constant $c \in \mathbb Z$ such that $|x_i - y_i| \in \{0,c\}$ for each $i=1, 2, \dots, k$; additionally, there must be at least one coordinate $i$ such that $x_i = y_i$.

Or perhaps you want to lay the groundwork for other, similar definitions by giving a more general definition as a preliminary step.

> We define a *$d$-dimensional linear move of length $c$* to be a move from a square $(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_k)$ to another square $(y_1, y_2, \dots, y_k)$ such that:
>
> - For $d$ of the indices $i \in \{1,\dots,k\}$, we have $|x_i - y_i| = c$;
> - For all other indices $i \in \{1,\dots,k\}$, we have $x_i = y_i$.
>
> A $k$-dimensional rook can make a $d$-dimensional linear move of any positive length, for all $d$ such that $1 \le d \le k-1$. A $k$-dimensional queen, on the other hand, can...

(Or maybe, "there is a set $I \subseteq \{1,\dots,k\}$ with $|I|=d$ such that for all indices $i \in I$, we have $|x_i - y_i|=c$, and for $i \notin I$, we have $x_i = y_i$".)

If you want to refer to the subset of squares where a rook can move to, then you can follow up with introducing notation for that subset, such as:

> We define $R(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_k) \subseteq \{0,1,\dots,n-1\}^k$ to be the set of all squares that a $k$-dimensional rook can reach in one move from the square $(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_k)$.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a very useful comment. I sent my preprint to the arXiv a couple of days ago, waiting for the announcement, then I am planning to revise it and submit the manuscript for the peer-review. In the introductory section, I define $3$ different types of of $k$-dimensional rooks and two types of $k$-dimensional bishops and queens... the above is the most powerful rook among the three since the second one is the rook from the Millennim 3D chess and the last one is the standard $k$-rook that changes only one of its $k$ coordinates at a time.

Comment: I call $C(n,k)$ the chessboard, which is $\{0,\dots,n-1\} \times \cdots \times \{0,\dots,n-1\} \subset \mathbb{R}^k$, and then I indicate as $S_t(X;n,k,x_1,\ldots,x_k)$ for given $t \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ the set of vertices of $C(n,k)$ that a piece $X$ (e.g., our powerful rook $R^{\star}$) can reach in $t$ moves (or less).
I think that the move rules of each of our $k$-pieces, $X$, are clear by the context (with the additional help of $34$ figures, their captions, and many examples), so I hope that the formal definitions are good enough, even if not very nice to be read.

Comment: Preprint available here (arXiv): https://arxiv.org/pdf/2311.00016v2.pdf